# Missing packages after cleaning node_modules

Tags: css, vue.js, npm

I had an issue: npm run watch was stuck after 10%, so I deleted node_modules directory and package-lock.json
But I guess I installed modules with npm install without using --save-dev, and after having reinstalled several of them I still get a warning and can't identify which package is missing here...

```
WARNING in ./resources/js/components/common/ContenuComponent.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=1a3ffd6c&scoped=true&lang=css& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/common/ContenuComponent.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=1a3ffd6c&scoped=true&lang=css&)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(476:2) Unable to find uri in 'background:url() no-repeat top left black'
 @ ./resources/js/components/common/ContenuComponent.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=1a3ffd6c&scoped=true&lang=css& (./node_modules/style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/common/ContenuComponent.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=1a3ffd6c&scoped=true&lang=css&) 2:14-388
 @ ./resources/js/components/common/ContenuComponent.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=1a3ffd6c&scoped=true&lang=css&
 @ ./resources/js/components/common/ContenuComponent.vue
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

I did:

- npm install postcss-loader --save-dev
- npm install style-loader --save-dev
- npm install css-loader --save-dev
- npm install file-loader --save-dev
- npm install vue-loader --save-dev

  Is there any way to identify what I am missing?
  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you remove `package-lock.json`, you remove references about which specific versions of each package were installed before. My guess is that there was an issue published within the `css-loader` module, which seems to be a dependency of a dependency of Laravel.

The easiest fix would be bringing back `package-lock.json`, removing node_modules again and reinstalling with `npm install`.

Comment: I found it in my bid (I hadn't thought about it... ooouf) and it worked, thank you so much. i remove it from my gitignore right now!

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you can try based on the information you have provided. You can try npm cache clean or npm cache clean --f (this is a force, which will ask you if you know what you are doing, you can proceed with the force). Once the cache has been cleaned, you can try running npm install again. Also check your version of NodeJS and make sure that whatever packages you're using is also supporting the version. Node -V and check and make sure that css loader supports your version of node.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, npm cache clean --f didn't work.
The  "css-loader": "^2.1.1"; node v10.15.3. I don't think I changed my node version, but indeed maybe I have too recent versions of the other plugins... Hard to find out what it wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

After I thought it had been fixed, I got the issue again today (worst actually, this time it was an error). So I went back to package-lock.json old version and after many tries and another hours lost, it worked.

I guess this is gonna happen again and obviously I cannot do that because I will add other packages in the future. I am wondering if there is any way to add all missing packages in package.json dev dependencies? I have no idea how to identify them?

It seems like npm install `ls node_modules` --save was working some years ago, so I m trying to dind something like this but reading in package-lock.json maybe (am I dreaming? :) )

Thanks a lot